# Randomly changing variable

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging

I'm trying to find an instance of an int in an array, and then print out the index of that int. The problem is the variable I'm using to store the number I'm checking keeps changing in the middle of inputs.

```
int num, size;
int arr[size];

cin >> num >> size;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (arr[i] == num){
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

return 0;
```

The input is this:

```
23
12
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23
```

While inputting the array arr, the variable num changes to 13 when arr[6] is assigned. What is causing the variable to switch?

Comment: At least `int arr[size];` is used where `size` isn't initialized yet. Note that dynamic array allocation on the stack like this, is a compiler extension but not standard c++.

Comment: @Cyber Agreed, that dupe completely answers what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one thing very wrong, and another issue is C++ compliancy.

These two lines:

```
int num, size;
int arr[size];  // wrong.
```

You are initializing an array with the value of `size`.  But what is the value of `size`?  It hasn't been set, therefore it will be some random value.  Maybe it will be 6, 100, 0, 843241, -342, you don't know.

Also, assume you *did* set `size` correctly before declaring the array.  Declaring arrays using variables is not standard C++.  Arrays must be declared using a constant expression.

If you want your program to be both correct and standard C++, use `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, size;
    cin >> num >> size;
    std::vector<int> arr(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == num)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, that's the c++ standard conforming solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num, size;
int arr[size];
cin >> num >> size;
```

You can´t use the value of size before you read it...

```
int num, size;
cin >> num >> size;
int arr[size];
```

Comment: This is also wrong. The static array size must be known **at compile time** not run time

Comment: @Cyber In fact a number of compilers (e.g. GCC) support it.

Comment: They do, but not according to the standard.

Comment: you can dyanmically create an array like this - arr = new (nothrow) int[size];

Comment: @mgrenier Why don't you post this as an answer with an appropriate working sample?

Comment: @Cyber Was the question if all compilers will support this? No. And the one of the OP does. And avoiding this error is important for vectors etc. too.

Comment: @deviantfan If you write code that only compiles correctly on specific compilers (short of actual platform dependent code) I wouldn't want to work with any of your code.

Comment: @Cyber I don´t, because I agree with you there.